# PostgreSQL multiple count() where conditions in a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I normally execute the following SQL queries in PostgreSQL 9.1 sequentially via psycopg2 every couple of seconds:

```
select count(type) from bag where type= 'fruit';
select count(type) from bag where type= 'vegtable';
select count(type) from bag where type= 'other';
select count(type) from bag where type= 'misc';
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in a single select query such that I get a count for each type even if that count is zero.  The following would work if it gave me the zero counts when there are zero for a given type.

```
 select type, count(*) from bag group by type;
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use derived table as anchor of the query:

```
select a.type, count(b.type) 
from (values ('fruit'), ('vegtable'), ('other'), ('misc')) as a(type)
    left outer join bag as b on b.type = a.type
group by a.type
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e36cb/2)</kbd>**

Comment: I threw an order by type at the end and it is exactly what I want.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many possible solutions for this. One is by generating all desired type in a subquery using `UNION ALL` and do a `LEFT JOIN` against `bag` table. In this case, all the `types` that you want to get will be shown on the result list and the non-existing type on table `bag` will have zero count. This will *almost* work on all RDBMS.

```
SELECT  a.type,
        COUNT(b.type) TotalCount
FROM
        (
            SELECT 'fruit' AS type UNION ALL
            SELECT 'vegtable' AS type UNION ALL
            SELECT 'other' AS type UNION ALL
            SELECT 'misc' AS type 
        ) AS a
        LEFT JOIN bag AS b
            ON a.type = b.type
GROUP   By a.type
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0b0ef/1)

Comment: Appreciate the help.  Thank you